# configuring spring configuration server to not publish on rabbitmq

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to configure Spring config server to NOT publish notifications at all?

There is a situation I want to use Spring config server but I don't want to use anything for messaging. I want my config clients to poll for changes.

What I have read sounds like default is localhost rabbitmq. I want to turn off (configure) that functionality of the config server.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the documentation. In starting up the configuration server I took out the dependency spring-cloud-start-bus-amqp and it seems to work fine without that.